# FB like catch not works with first like

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

MY code is

```
            jQuery(window).load(function(){
                jQuery("#myDiv").jcFacebookLike({href:"http://www.facebook.com/jaspreetchahal.org",
                show_faces:"false",
                layout:"button_count",
                    callbackLike:function(response) {
                        jQuery("#log").append(jQuery("<div></div>").html("Liked: "+response));
                    },
                    callbackUnLike:function(response) {
                        jQuery("#log").append(jQuery("<div></div>").html("Un-Liked: "+response +" - <hr>Please think about your decision again. If this plugin could be a help then keep liking my FB page. I have got lot to share :)"));
                    }

                });
            })
</script>
```

this is for catching like and dislike events,

and fb default init,problem is that when user clicks like first time, and authorizes via fb account, callback not works, after that, when user dislikes all callbacks are working fine.

here is the example

http://jaspreetchahal.org/examples/jquery-examples/likes/jcFacebookLike.html

Comment: why do you want to catch the like/dislike event? that´s a weird way to get callbacks for likes, especially when there is a native way...

Comment: @luschn to give some advantages if user likes our fb page from website

Comment: rewarding users or gating content for likes is not allowed. you must read the platform policy.